# Subsetting dataframes with loop - failing

Tags: r

I have a loop that's causing me not only time problems as it's taking a long time to run on a dataset of 30k, but not providing the correct output.

```
interval <- days(10)

df <- data.frame(CompanyID = c(23512, 51250, 12515, 51250, 52512, 51250), 
                 openingDate = as.Date(c("1999-07-15", "1995-02-01", 
                 "2001-01-25", "1995-02-04", "2004-07-08", "1996-05-25")),
                 Rev = c(1000, 2000, 4000, 5000, 5500, 2050))

for(id in unique(df$CompanyID)){
    df[, c("groupID")] <- NA
    df[, c("updatedRev")] <- df$Rev

tempDF <- df %>% filter(CompanyID == id)

if(nrow(tempDF) == 1){
  #arbitrary unique ID
  df$groupID[df$CompanyID == id] <- paste(id) 
}

else{
  dfDateRange <- tempDF[order(tempDF$openingDate),]

  while(nrow(dfDateRange) > 0) { # until table is empty

    earliest_date <- dfDateRange$openingDate[1] #earliest date within subset
    within_dates <- dfDateRange %>% filter(openingDate <= earliest_date + interval) 
    # all data within the interval

    # values to replace in subset that falls within date range
    # Revenue
    df$updatedRev[(df$CompanyID == id) &
                    (df$openingDate %in% within_dates$openingDate )] <-
    sum(within_dates$Rev)

    # Generate Group ID 
    df$groupID[(df$CompanyID == id) &
                 (df$openingDate %in% within_dates$openingDate)] <- paste(id)

    # moving on to rows outside of date range
    dfDateRange <- dfDateRange %>% 
       filter(dfDateRange$openingDate > (earliest_date + interval))

  }
 }
}
```

The translation of this code is:

- Take in a large dataframe, create a temp group ID column to be used later and a updatedRev column that will be overwritten later dependent on conditions
- For every unique CompanyID, create a dataframe and assign a new ID
- If there are multiple incidences of CompanyID, then we subset on the condition that all incidences fall into a certain date range
- For those that fall into the specified date range, we'll override Revenue values and assign a group ID to that group (in this example, rows 2 and 4)
- For those that fall outside the date range, go to the next earliest opening date - and see which rows fall within that range and follow steps beginning from the for loop

Two questions about this. When I return the dataframe after running the loop, I get back

```
> df
  CompanyID openingDate  Rev groupID updatedRev
1     23512  1999-07-15 1000    <NA>       1000
2     51250  1995-02-01 2000    <NA>       2000
3     12515  2001-01-25 4000    <NA>       4000
4     51250  1995-02-04 5000    <NA>       5000
5     52512  2004-07-08 5500   52512       5500
6     51250  1996-05-25 2050    <NA>       2050
```

When I should get back:

```
  CompanyID openingDate  Rev groupID updatedRev
1     23512  1999-07-15 1000   23512       1000
2     51250  1995-02-01 2000   51250       7000
3     12515  2001-01-25 4000   12515       4000
4     51250  1995-02-04 5000   51250       7000
5     52512  2004-07-08 5500   52512       5500
6     51250  1996-05-25 2050   51250       2050
```

*note, the updatedRev did not update to replace values with summed values of duplicates CompanyID's 51250 that fall into a 10 day range of each other.

My other question, when I wrap this around in a function - say `test()` and run the function `test(df)` - `df` does not change. Why is that?

Note: I will be adjusting the groupId later to be more accurate, so that row 6 can be differentiated between Row 2 & 4. Just want to get this question up as that's just a line adjustment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided I understood your problem statement correctly (unfortunately your code & translation are quite abstruse, see my comment below), the following `tidyverse` approach reproduces your expected output

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    rowid_to_column("row") %>%                      
    mutate(
        openingDate = as.Date(openingDate),
        groupID = CompanyID) %>%
    group_by(groupID) %>%
    arrange(openingDate) %>%
    mutate(
        diff = openingDate - lag(openingDate),
        grp = cumsum(+!(is.na(diff) | diff < 10))) %>%
    group_by(groupID, grp) %>%
    mutate(updatedRev = sum(Rev)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-diff, -grp) %>%
    arrange(row)
## A tibble: 6 x 6
#    row CompanyID openingDate   Rev groupID updatedRev
#  <int>     <dbl> <date>      <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>
#1     1    23512. 1999-07-15  1000.  23512.      1000.
#2     2    51250. 1995-02-01  2000.  51250.      7000.
#3     3    12515. 2001-01-25  4000.  12515.      4000.
#4     4    51250. 1995-02-04  5000.  51250.      7000.
#5     5    52512. 2004-07-08  5500.  52512.      5500.
#6     6    51250. 1996-05-25  2050.  51250.      2050.
```

Explanation: Group entries by `groupID = CompanyID`, sort by `openingDate`, calculate differences between successive `openingDate`s, and give `grp` labels based on whether successive `openingDate`s are within 10 days; then group by `groupID` *and* `grp`, and create `updatedRev` as the sum of grouped `Rev` values. The last steps are tidying & re-arranging the `data.frame` to reproduce the expected output.

I'm creating the extra column `row` only to help compare results with those from your expected output. Remove if not wanted.

---

Your code has several issues, readibility being one of them, but most of them related to the `for` and `while` loops. For example I don't understand what you're trying to do in

```
for(id in unique(df$CompanyID)){
    df[, c("groupID")] <- NA
    df[, c("updatedRev")] <- df$Rev
```

You don't use `id` anywhere inside the `for` loop, and you can achieve the same simply by doing

```
df$groupID <- NA
df$updatedRev <- df$Rev
```

---

### Update

To get unique `groupID`s for observations that are `>=10` days apart, you could concatenate `companyID` and `grp`

```
df %>%
rowid_to_column("row") %>%
mutate(openingDate = as.Date(openingDate)) %>%
group_by(CompanyID) %>%
arrange(openingDate) %>%
mutate(
    diff = openingDate - lag(openingDate),
    grp = cumsum(+!(is.na(diff) | diff < 10)),
    groupID = paste(CompanyID, grp, sep = "_")) %>%
group_by(groupID, grp) %>%
mutate(updatedRev = sum(Rev)) %>%
ungroup() %>%
select(-diff, -grp) %>%
arrange(row)
## A tibble: 6 x 6
#    row CompanyID openingDate   Rev groupID updatedRev
#  <int>     <dbl> <date>      <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
#1     1    23512. 1999-07-15  1000. 23512_0      1000.
#2     2    51250. 1995-02-01  2000. 51250_0      7000.
#3     3    12515. 2001-01-25  4000. 12515_0      4000.
#4     4    51250. 1995-02-04  5000. 51250_0      7000.
#5     5    52512. 2004-07-08  5500. 52512_0      5500.
#6     6    51250. 1996-05-25  2050. 51250_1      2050.
```

Comment: Thank you! I know the code is all over the place, was using someone's else approach with this and appreciate the better method! Two questions: what does `cumsum(+` do? Additionally, if I was hoping to get the group ID to only be the same for those rows that fell in the same date range, is that possible? As you can see I just used the CompanyID, but ideally I was trying to make it more unique. So rows 2 & 4, would be distinguished from row 6 using the group ID?

Comment: @S31 `cumsum(+!...)` returns the cumulative sum of the logical condition such that `TRUE` equals `0` and `FALSE` equals `1`. `grp` gets incremented when there is an observation that is `>=10` days apart from the previous observation. This is to ensure that we sum the correct entries within every group. To give unique `groupID`'s you could concatenate `companyID` and the `grp` label; I've updated my answer to demonstrate. Please take a look.

Comment: Man, brilliant. Thank you.